# Why wrapping your code in resolved prop makes your sync code act like async code?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, promise, es6-promise

Loop inside of the promise works like sync code, for example:

```js
console.log('im working')
function proLoop(){
    return Promise((resolve ,rejects)=>{
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000000; i++) {}
        console.log('loop is done')
    })
}

proLoop();

console.log('im working')
```

So even if we write is like promise it will get more time and freezes our code In other words it will works synchronically.

i find a solution but why it works?

so the solution is just warp your code as like resolved promise

like this

```
return new Promise.resolve().then( ()=>{
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000000; i++) {}
    console.log('loop is done')
})
```

but why and how???

Comment: `Promise.then()` will execute next tick. However, it's still going to freeze the thread starting next tick, it's not a actually solving the issue. Just delays the loop execution.

Comment: yep . if just use `.then()` it will feeze  my code but by using`Promise.resolve().then()` it works

Comment: Putting the loop in a `then` callback will still freeze the page, just a bit later (after the `'im working'` log). Nothing to be gained there.

Comment: From your comment, I think you are confused of what `event loop` is. You may have a look of the [document](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).

Comment: why Promise.resolve().then() can make sync code to async code

Comment: @scriptydude, did you read the document in the comment above before you are asking `why Promise.resolve().then() can make sync code to async code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the `for` loop will block the main event loop. The difference is when the `for` loop starts.

In the first case, the function passed to `new Promise` is executed **immediately**. It therefore blocks the rest of the function that creates it.

In the second case, the function passed to `then()` is queued up to run next time the event loop is free. The function that created it therefore finishes **first** and then the `for` loop runs. (If that's the goal, then its a pretty unintuitive approach, and using [`setImmediate`](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate) (in browsers) or Node's [`process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-process-nexttick) would be neater.)

If you wanted to shunt the work done by the `for` loop off the main event loop so it didn't block anything you would use a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) or [Worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) depending on what JavaScript runtime you were using.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things you need to understand here:

1. Promises don't make something *asynchronous* - they are a notification mechanism for something that's *already* asynchronous. Promises notify you of the success or failure of an operation that's *already* asynchronous.

   Callback function of the promise constructor is called *synchronously*; it is called synchronously to start an operation that's *already* asynchronous.

   In your case, promise constructor contains synchronous code; this is why it blocks other code.
2. Moving the loop inside the callback function of `then` executes the loop asynchronously because the callback function of `then` is invoked asynchronously.

   Note: Even though the callback function of `then` method is invoked asynchronously, once it starts executing, no other code will execute until the synchronous code inside the callback is executed completely.

Comment: I think you didn't get the point let me explain... even by using then it self it not works corectly  and the code executes in the the same ***event loop***
however if you make it like resolved promise then it will works and executes in next event loop

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code where the loop is inside the `then` method's callback and it is still invoked synchronously?

Comment: @scriptydude, all the asynchronous operation is using the same `event loop`. The execution order is how they handled by the `event loop`.